# Read from keyboard and write to file (emu8086)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I need some help with this problem. I have to read something from keyboard and then write it to a .txt file.

So far i got this code that just writes something into a .txt file:

```
org  100h 

jmp start

dir db "c:\MyFolder", 0
file db "c:\MyFolder\MyFile.txt", 0
text db "Some text"
text_size = $ - offset text
handle dw ?

start:
mov ax, cs
mov dx, ax
mov es, ax


   mov dx, offset dir
   mov ah, 39h
   int 21h


mov ah, 3ch
mov cx, 0
mov dx, offset file
int 21h
jc err
mov handle, ax

; write to file:
mov ah, 40h
mov bx, handle
mov dx, offset text
mov cx, text_size
int 21h

mov ah, 3eh
mov bx, handle
int 21h
err:
nop


    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

And this code which reads something from keyboard into a buffer:

```
org 100h
        mov dx, offset buffer
        mov ah, 0ah
        int 21h
        jmp print
        buffer db 10,?, 10 dup(' ')
        print:      

        mov dh, 1
    mov dl, 0
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 2
    int 10h  

        xor bx, bx
        mov bl, buffer[1]
        mov buffer[bx+2], '$'
        mov dx, offset buffer + 2
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h
        ret
```

Two simple little programs that summarize my problem, but i have no ideea how to combine them.
I should basically try to write the buffer to a .txt file but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: it works the same way as `; write to file:` in the first example. You need the handle, the length (after calling int 21/9 in buffer[1]), the pointer to the text( = buffer+2), and then call 21/40h.

Comment: Yes, but it also writes some random characters and it starts on the second line of the .txt file. Where could be the problem?

Comment: after input, buffer[1] is the length of the inserted string as a byte. 'write' wants the size as a word (in CX), so if you read buffer[1] to CL, make sure that CH is 0. `XOR CX,CX` and `MOV CL, buffer[1]` should do the job. take a look at CX bevor you write the file (use a debugger), and compare this with the filesize your file has, afterwards